# Should type microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions be accessible through Azure Resource Graph

Tags: azure, kusto, azure-resource-graph

Is type `microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions` available through Azure Resource Graph?

### Context

I'm hoping to query Azure Resource Graph to fetch all roles which have specific permissions.
Looking around I found `microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions` which seems to be a good starting point; it's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/reference/supported-tables-resources#authorizationresources) and is listed under `tables` in `Azure Resource Graph Explorer` / double clicking it adds the line `| where type == "microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions"` which seems promising.

However, when I run the below Kusto this type doesn't show up:

```
Search-AzGraph -query @'
resources 
| where type startswith "Microsoft.Aut" 
| distinct type
'@
```

The response is simply:

```
type
----
microsoft.automation/automationaccounts
microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/runbooks
```

I do have access to view role definitions though; as running `Get-AzRoleDefinition` produces a list of results.

Is there something more I need to do to make this type visible via Kusto; or is it simply not yet available through ARG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the table to authorizationresources and that should provide the definitions:

```
$query = 'authorizationresources | where type == "microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions"' 
Search-AzGraph -query $query -UseTenantScope
```

Comment: Ah - thank-you; I'd not even thought to question the table the resources would be under.  That works perfectly.